# How to add providers in terraform aws?

Tags: mysql, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/mysql: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a
provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For terraform > 0.13 you need to add a [required_providers snippet for any un-official provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/requirements.html) (un-official means not owned by HashiCorp and not part of their registry). There was one supported by HashiCorp [but it is discontinued](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-mysql) (you could potentially use it if you downgrade to TF12).

If you are aware of a community provided one a code snippet similar to the one for docker below should suffice:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}
```

where in source you will give a link to the provider source repo/registry.

Comment: `terraform {
required_providers {
aws = {
source = "hashicorp/aws"
version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}`

now this is the code I'm using. Can I add sql provider here.


Since I don't know this I created a instance and installed sql in it @Nick

Comment: you can as a long you provide a link to the source for it (so terraform knows where to download it from). Take a look at the link to the documentation that I posted in my answer above.